# android - libjingle_peerconnection_so.so

Tags: android, webrtc, apprtcdemo

i am using android source code for web rtc that placed in [code.google](http://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk)

but when i am trying to run this application in my device and enter a room name to connect in it click on call this error appears in my logcat:

```
No implementation found for native Lorg/webrtc/PeerConnectionFactory;.initializeFieldTrials:(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Fatal error: Native method not found: org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.initializeFieldTrials:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Comment: Have you been able to fix that?

Comment: Yes, i am also getting the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

You might try building using the automated method provided at http://tech.pristine.io/automated-webrtc-building/.

Comment: more details please .. i just need the correct file of libjingle_peerconnection_so.so to work with webrtc code.google example "http://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftalk%2Fexamples%2Fandroid"

Comment: The link in this answer is dead, it used to point to a blog post. However, the build scripts [are still available here](https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-build-scripts).